# What is so うまそう about the flower name スノードロップ?

Tags: words

I've seen people saying that this flower has an うまそう name. Why is that? Does it sound similar to some candy or what?

Examples include https://twitter.com/hanabot_aph/status/699851458590543872
or 24th episode of 怪盗セイントテール, where Asuka can't remember what the flower is called and all he knows is that it has a tasty sounding name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because ドロップ is a type of hard candy, similar to something like "lemon drops" (though not necessarily lemon). See [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%89%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%97) wikipedia page for details.

It may also be because of the connection of スノー to スノーコーン(snow cone). I am not sure how often this word is used in Japanese but you can see an example [here](http://www.amazon.co.jp/Nostalgia-%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A2-%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8D%E6%B0%B7%E6%A9%9F-%E3%82%B9%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3/dp/B004L8EXZA).

Comment: 「スノーコーン」 is 初耳 to me ｗ

Comment: Yeah, I thought it wasn't used frequently, as I hadn't heard it myself until I did a search (: